# OOP and Persistence

Tags: oop, architecture

In the spirit of tell don't ask and never let an object get into an invalid state oop design, I'm wondering how persistence would be handled in a dynamic environment.

For a contrived example, imagine you need to write a POS application for an airline.  You can only sell seats that are available.  Seats are grouped such that plane -> sections -> rows -> seats.  If a section is unavailable then all rows and therefore seats in that section are also unavailable.  And obviously if a row in unavailable then all seats in the row are also not available.
Now the environment is highly dynamic in that maintenance personnel may be making sections, rows, or seats available/unavailable frequently.  Further, imagine it's somewhat expensive to build the airplane object graph.  However without constructing the entire graph for each sale attempt I don't see how you can keep business rules out of the persistence layer, which in my mind is an absolute must.
Is oop just not a viable choice for this kind of problem?

Edit:
If it makes a difference, assume the system is persisted by a db server and the inputs to the system are made via http thin clients.

Answer (score 0):

I don't see why you can't construct the airplane object once, and manage it on the fly? You'd have to make it safe for concurrent access, but isn't this EXACTLY the type of problem OOP is good for?

Maybe I misunderstand your scenario.

Comment: You know that initially, all seats are empty, and each time a seat assignment attempt is made a routine runs that checks if the seat is invalid, then if the row is invalid, then if the plane is full.

Comment: I wouldn't even use a graph for this problem, as I understand it.

Comment: Well that's the problem.  Where does the airplane object live?  Imagine the sales terminal is a web client.  In order to get a list of seats for sale you need to know about the entire plane.  And further, by the time you enter the customer info into the system, the seat you are selling may have become unavailable.

Comment: Not if you use a locking strategy on your data structure. Whenever an attendant selects an open seat, if it is open at the time they select it, the software acquires a lock on that seat and it cannot become unavailable during information entry. 

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lock_%28computer_science%29

Comment: Sure you could use some mutex scheme if a single object were stored in memory somewhere.  I'm not sure how you would achieve this is a disconnected environment though.  If the input to the system were web based how would you do this?

Comment: A central server holds the airplane structure and the web based terminals send requests to it. It'd be inefficient for each terminal to try to sync a copy of an airplane object with all the others.

Answer (score 0):

Separate seat availability from from the plane itself.  The whole plane can't be reconstructed on each request, but the seat availability might be able to be requeried each time.

availableSeats = availabilityService.getAvailableSeats(flightId)

availableSections = planeObj.getAvailableSections(seatAvailabilityList)